# How to setup PostGIS JDBC with Hibernate?

Tags: postgis, java

I try to setup an Java Application with Hibernate and PostGIS but I always get nasty exceptions like :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.type.CustomType.<init>
  (Lorg/hibernate/usertype/UserType;[Ljava/lang/String;)V ....
```

After looking around I got the impression that the PostGIS JDBC driver is not compatible with Hibernate, which would be strange.

I'm using :

- hibernate-spatial 1.1.1
- PostGIS JDBC 2.0 (the link for 2.1 is dead ...)
- postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4
- Hibernate 3.2.5

The table I try to map is

```
CREATE TABLE "cRef" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "contenttype" varchar(200),
    "contentid" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('cRef','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

from my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialect
        </property>
```

and my classpath contains:

```
hibernate-spatial-1.1.1.jar and 
hibernate-spatial-postgis-1.1.1.jar
```

Can anyone recommend me a working setup? Or give me some hints, how to get this setup running?

The complete stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.type.CustomType.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/usertype/UserType;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialect.<clinit>(PostgisDialect.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2005)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:40)
    at org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizard.generateClasses(HibernateCodeGenWizard.java:338)
    at org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizard.instantiate(HibernateCodeGenWizard.java:442)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1022)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:589)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:432)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:253)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper$ProgressInstantiatingIterator.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:180)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1597)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1541)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2000(WizardDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2165)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1452)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2032)
Caused: org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem: task failed due to
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor.post(RequestProcessor.java:424)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2211)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1516)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1600(WizardDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:457)
    at $Proxy48.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:158)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1072)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1072)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1106)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1094)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:126)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:273)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1079)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1650)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1602)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1013)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1003)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.showDialog(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:260)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.run(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:186)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:158)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Did you include the postgis provider for hibernate-spatial listed here http://www.hibernatespatial.org/download.html

Comment: Yes, it is in my classpath, I extended the description in the original question

Answer (score 1):

I have found a reference to an error similar to yours (that's why I needed the full stacktrace):

http://hibernate-spatial.1140993.n2.nabble.com/bytea-type-instead-of-geometry-tp6304943p6305521.html

and follow the discussion from that point. It seems you have all correct dependencies setup, but maybe in the thread you will find something that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/py5gol/hibernate-spatial-tutorial) is the full code of hibernate spatial tutorial for Hibernate 3.x. It's based on maven, so dependencies should not be a problem since they were defined as described in tutorial.

Just git clone the repository and update src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml with your database connection info.

To run:

```
mvn clean compile 
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="event.EventManager" -Dexec.args="store POINT(10 5)"
```